# Various ways to say "nice to meet you"

Tags: mandarin, expressions, greetings

When I first started learning Chinese I knew the in order to say "Nice to meet you" or "Pleased to meet you," I had to use the following expression:

> 很高兴见到您。

But recently I've come across other expressions to say the same thing:

> - 认识你，我很高兴。
>     **or**
> - 很高兴认识你。

My questions are the following: Are there any differences in style and "situation" between those two? Which ones is used when? And finally, are there other expressions to express the same thing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 很高兴见到您。

means glad to see you. It's usually used if you know (or heard of) someone for a long time, but haven't seen him/her for sometime(first time in case of heard of). For example, you would use 很高兴见到您 to greet someone you know from the internet. It's a bit weird to say 很高兴见到您 to someone you know very well or see everyday.

If it's the first time you meet/know someone, I think

> 认识你，我很高兴。

is more suitable, which means I'm glad to know(meet) you.
you can also say

> 我很高兴认识你。

same meaning as above.

you can also say

> 幸会

which means "glad to meet you", and is usually used when the first time you meet someone. Usually it's used twice together, so you would say 幸会,幸会 rather than just one 幸会.

> 久仰大名

means "I've heard about you for a long time"

> 见到您感到很荣幸

means "It's an honor to meet(see) you". Or

> 认识您感到很荣幸

means "It's an honor to know you."

> 初次见面,请多关照

It's originally from Japanese and often used in Taiwan. It means "It's the first time meeting you, please be kind."

Comment: So the one I knew is actually used as a "long time I didn't see you"? And the "renshi ni" one is used for first-times? Interesting...

Comment: Yeah, 很高兴见到您 is used when you know or heard of someone for a long time, but it's the first time you actually see the person. For example, if you are meeting someone you know from the internet. It's a bit weird to say 很高兴见到您 to someone you know well or see everyday.

Comment: Why don't you include that? :D Thanks for the nice answer. I'll accept your answer, but if you don't mind I reserve the right to ask you further stuff in the future... :D

Comment: No problems. I've edit the answer slightly. :)

Answer (score 3):

@StarCub pretty much covers it, so I'll just add:

> 看到你我很开心

*I'm so happy to see you*

Another one which is quite common, but doesn't have the same meaning as your question:

> 好久不见了

*Long time no see!*

Comment: `好开心看到你啦`，it just a little weird.. :P

Comment: @Kjuly - Couldn't you say that to someone close or a family member your haven't seen in a while? 我好开心看到你

Comment: Mum..that's fine. However, I'd use `很高兴见到你`. `开心` is often used in written language. But a closer friend, you can use `见到你我真开心!` :p

Answer (score 2):

很高兴认识你 is usually used when FIRST meeting with someone, while 认识你，我很高兴。is more used after knowing each other for a while, could be just minutes, hours, and even days or months, to express the feeling that "I'm really happy to have a friend like you"

Another good one could be: 认识你真好 at first meet，literally it means to get to know you is really good.

Answer (score 1):

很高兴认识你 ---- Common
认识你，我很高兴 ---- Common
如果给高兴一个定义，那就是认识了你 ---- It is a humor way that I liked. Someone might be moved to tears if you say this, so don't use it easily.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct translations, but saying "nice to meet you" is not a common social etiquette in China, according to my life experience. If I meet someone for the first time, and he said this to me, I may feel weird. Maybe this makes people feel you are too enthusiastic. Perhaps saying 你好 and then shaking hands is enough in some formal situations. And when your meeting is going to an end, it would be very nice to say something like "今天认识各位朋友很高兴".